# How do I link Twitter API credentials with my websites login credentials?

Tags: api, asp-classic, twitter, linkedin-api

I was just wondering, I want to associate a Twitter and LinkedIn account with my systems accounts. Which would allow them to post to interact with them without needing to log in to the other systems.

Is there a way to store the social (twitter / LI) usernames and passwords and associate them with my system and vis versa.

E.g. If I login using my native details (email  / password) I can access the API features of my social network accounts?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for Twitter, but with LinkedIn you could follow this basic workflow:

1. Register an 'application' with LinkedIn. Your site will use this application for all communication with the LinkedIn API.
2. Have the user authorize your site (your application really), to access their account via the LinkedIn API.
3. Retrieve the user's unique LinkedIn ID, as well as their access tokens, and store those in your user account database, associated with their existing account.

Then, when they return and log in to your site, any calls you need to make to LinkedIn can be done via the stored access token, rather than having to have them manually allow you to have access again.